# Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.PreparedStatement to jdbcDemo.PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

```
package jdbcDemo;
import java.sql.*;

public class PreparedStatement {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            // using SQL to insert,edit,delete information from a database
            Connection myConn =null;
            PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
            ResultSet myRs=null;

        try{
            // 1.make a connection to database
            myConn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping_cart","root","1578");

            //2.create a statement
            myStmt=  myConn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM shopping_cart.customers where total_cost>? and items_number>?");

            //3.set parameters
            myStmt.setDouble(1,2);
            myStmt.setDouble(2,40);             
            myRs=myStmt.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
```

In the step 2, I am trying to create a prepared statement, but got a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.PreparedStatement to jdbcDemo. PreparedStatement" . I googled it , most of the answers say I should import java.sql.*, and I did but still got the answer.

Comment: Rename your class `PreparedStatement`, it shadows the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` `import`. Or use the fully qualified class name `java.sql.PreparedStatement myStmt=null;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your own `PreparedStatement`, and it is confusing the compiler.

Change the name of your class or replace

```
PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
```

with

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
```